# Weak Gradient of the Unit Ball

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2,$ and $f(\mathbf{x})=1$ if $||\mathbf{x}||\leq R\in\mathbb{R}$,    $f(\mathbf{x})=0$ otherwise. I want to find the weak gradient of $f$ in the dual space of compactly supported $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ test functions, $\phi$. This is my attempt for the derivative with respect to $r$ by just following definitions, Fubini, and integration by parts:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}T_f(\phi)=-T_f\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right)=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^R\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}rdrd\theta=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(R\phi(R,\theta)- \int_{0}^R\phi dr\right)d\theta$$ $$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^R(1-r\delta(R-r))\phi drd\theta.$$
Granted that this work is correct, can I conclude that the weak derivative of $f$ with respect to $r$ is $\frac{1}{r}-\delta(R-r)$? Or do I have the wrong idea?

Comment: What's $R$? The unit ball is a set, not a function - what do you really mean by $f$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis good point. I edited the question.

Comment: How exactly (!) do you get your second equality? Seems to involve polar coordinates, but I don't see how/why $\partial \phi / \partial r $ pops up.

Comment: @PhoemueX I'm using the distribution $T_f(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\phi fdA$

Comment: OK,  different question: What do you mean by $(\partial /\partial r) T_f $? The usual coordinates on $\Bbb {R}^2$ are $x_1,x_2$, there is no $r $. Also, since you say that you want to compute the gradient, you would need to compute at least two partial derivatives.

Comment: If I have the right idea about the derivative in r, then the derivative in $\theta$ is just about the same thing, but in that case $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},$ of course.The reason I'm using polar coordinates is because of the symmetry of f in that coordinate system.